# Laravel 5.5 Eloquent groupBy on ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

For example, I need take `tags` name and its not duplicate each `categories`

here my `model`

Post.php

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function tags() : belongsToMany
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Tag.php

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

and here what I do.

```
Category::with(['posts.tags' => function($query){
        $query->groupBy('name'); // i need show tags name and group it, so its will not duplcate
    }])->get();
```

for `$query->groupBy('name');` name is `tags` name.

example

```
Categpry A
|__Title A
   |__Tag A
   |__Tag B
   |__Tag C
   |__Tag D
|__Title B
   |__Tag A
   |__Tag D
   |__Tag E
```

the result must be `Tag A, Tag B, Tag C, Tag D, Tag E` i don't have an idea how to right now, any have a solution?...

thank you!

Comment: What is your current result?

Comment: error `tagsIlluminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'blog.categories.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `categories`.*, `post_tag`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `post_category`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `post_category`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `post_category`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` ......'`

Comment: The `Title A` is post title, right? I think you should get the data and group them by PHP code instead of SQL query.

Comment: yes it's post title